# ajax get request to laravel 5 controller doesn't work in mozilla

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, request, mozilla

I have the following issue in laravel 5:

In my js file I have written the code

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: '/ads/getcategories',
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus, errorThrown, jqXHR);
        },
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            _this.renderCategories(response);
        }
    });
```

In my laravel 5 route I file have written:

```
Route::get('ads/getcategories', 'AdsController@getCategories');
```

And finaly in my laravel 5 controller file the method I have written

```
public function getCategories()
{
        return '{}';
}
```

I just want to return empty json object. This works great on webkit browsers - chrome and opera but on mozilla and IE11 doesn't work. I wrote the console.log for ajax error and the messages are:
IE11 - parseerror 
Mozilla - error

Just that. I tried the ajax request with mozilla add-ons for rest requests and the results are ok, but when I tried to get the request in the page in the browser the request returs error.

**SOLVED**: Thanks to IE11 response

Mozilla still returns nothing except just error.

Adblock blocks the get request but how to do the ajax for the all users which are using adblock for mozilla and IE?

Comment: _"the request returs error"_ What is error message? Have you tried with `dataType:"text", contentType:"text/plain"`?

Comment: Ok I just tried, but still no efect.

Comment: E11 message "parseerror". Mozilla message "error"

Comment: _"Ok I just tried, but still no efect."_ What do you mean by "still no efect"? Was error logged with `dataType:"text"` option set?

Comment: responseText:undefined; statusText:"error"; That is the response error in Mozilla. I attached image in the post

Comment: thanks for the reply SOLVED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** Thanks to IE11 response

Mozilla still returns nothing except just error.

Adblock blocks the get request but how to do the ajax for the all users which are using adblock for mozilla and IE?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **Response::json()** method in your controllers.

```
public function getCategories()
{
        return response()->json();
}
```

It will set the correct content type (which is application/json) and should be parsed easily by Mozilla and IE.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but in the origial method I used the response()->json() method. I tried just to return the response()->json() but still the same.

Comment: Was this the solution? If so, you should mark this answer as accepted. If not, please post your answer.